# Select all entries that have multiple associated versions

Tags: sql, sqlite

Basically I want a select statement that selects ID, and Version, but each ID has multiple versions, so I want to select all ID's in the table and each version associated with each ID.

If I just do:

```
select ID, Version FROM Table
```

then I only get an ID and it's associated most recent version, I don't get multiple entries for ID=X and the multiple versions associated with ID X, etc

Example of data I want:

```
ID = 1, Version = 0
ID = 1, Version = 1.0
ID = 1, Version = 2.0
ID = 2, Version = 0
ID = 2, Version = 1.0
ID = 2, Version = 2.0
ID = 2, Version = 3.0
ID = 3, Version = 0
ID = 4, Version = 0
ID = 4, Version = 1.0

etc etc
```

Comment: If your simple select only gets the most recent version, then your table would not seem to have the earlier versions.

Comment: I agree with @GordonLinoff

Comment: It does have more versions, because if I do a select ID, Version FROM Table where ID = 1, I get all the versions for ID = 1, but if I select ALL ID's like above, it only lists the recent version

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table structure include 2 columns ID (*see Note*) and version AND a row existed for every combination of row/version then SELECT ID, version would list all the rows.

e.g. `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS details (id INTEGER, version TEXT);`

And it is populated as follows :-

[image]

Then the result of `SELECT id,version from details;` would be :-

[image]

Or if the query were `SELECT 'ID= ' ||id||', Version= ' || version AS vercol  FROM details;` it would be (to cater for how you have shown you want the result) :-

[image]

- Note where the column named id is not an alias of rowid (i.e it is not defined as `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`).

#### However

If the structure and usage is not based upon the above then you will likely encounter issues.

For example the following stores the latest version (and other versions) :-

[image]

Then `SELECT id, version FROM details_alt;` would result in what you appear to be describing i.e (the otherversion columns are ignored in this usage):-

[image]

To manipulate such a structure and either calculating the other than highest versions or including other columns would be quite complex. For example this is part way towards doing the former :-

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN version < 1 THEN 'ID= '||id||', Version=0'
        WHEN version < 2 THEN 'ID= '||id||' Version=0, 1.0'
        WHEN version < 3 THEN 'ID= '||id||' Version=0, 1.0, 2.0'
        WHEN version < 4 THEN 'ID= '||id||' Version=0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0'
    END AS idcol
FROM details_alt
```

and would result in :-

[image]

In short if your table isn't structured as initially shown, which it would appear to be the case, you are introducing unnecessary complexity and are not following well established database design techniques.

**The answer, again if not using the initial structure, is to utilise a design along the lines of the initial design shown.**

**Otherwise you should amend your question to show the table's structure and how it is utilised when storing with an example of actual data.**

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as

```
 SELECT ID , Version FROM Table WHERE ID='X'
```

Here `X` is your ID number

Comment: I don't want ID = X, I want all ID's in the table

Comment: That's mean you want to get all the ID and all the versions assigned with each ID. Am i right ?

Comment: Why  aren't you trying `SELECT ID, Version FROM Table ORDER BY ID, Version` ?

Comment: As you mentioned `then I only get an ID and it's associated most recent version` , that's mean you are not on mariadb or whatever console. Can you explain which language you are trying to implement this query?

Answer (score 0):

honestly, your question is kinda confusing because

```
select ID, Version From table
```

would bring all data from table, I think the table is big and thats why it looks like it doesnt show all Versions for each id, So Try using an Order by .

```
  select ID, Version FROM Table
    order by ID, Version
```